# Is Asteraceae and Compositae the same family?

Tags: botany, classification

I'm wondering what taxonomic family sunflowers (*Helianthus*) belong to. Although it's mentioned it belongs to family Asteraceae it is also a composite flower. So it belongs to Asteraceae or Compositae or both?
And do they refer to the same family or to different families?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteraceae#Etymology not the most scientific source, but they seem to be synonyms.

Comment: There are a number of plant families that, for historical reasons, have two accepted family names. In addition to Asteraceae/Compositae, there's also Fabaceae/Leguminosae, Poaceae/Gramineae, and others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are either treated or even declared to be synonyms in all the texts using both of the terms that I have ever read.

Just one reference: the nearest *Flora* on my desk, G. Marconi, F. Corbetta, *Flora della Pianura Padana e dell'Appennino Settentrionale*, uses the notation *Compositae* = *Asteraceae*.

It is worth to note that *Compositae*, 'composite ones' in Latin, refers to the their typical [capitulum](http://www.tolweb.org/asteraceae) inflorescence, while *Asteraceae* comes from [*Aster*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_%28genus%29), a genus belonging to the family, meaning 'star' in Latin, which represents an allusion to the shape of the inflorescence of *Aster*, and of many other species, which is supposed to look like a star whose rays are represented by the [ligules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ligule) of the ligulate tiny flowers of the capitulum. Nevertheless, there also are species of the family having no ligulate flowers, for ex. [*Tanacetum vulgare*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tansy).